# Python-for in messagebox message

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, printing, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I have a list of products

```
products = ["meat","salad","tomatoes"]
```

And I want to display them in a tkinter messagebox object, as the message.
So want something like this:

```
This products are already in the list:
-meat
-salad
-tomatoes
```

But how can I put in the string to output as the message all the elements in the products list?
Is that even possible?

I was woundering if you can use loops in this...

Comment: So, do you have an issue constructing a string or putting it into the MessageBox?

Comment: Since I have to give a string to the messagebox widget, I was woundering if I could usa another method, instead of creating a string a part, and then putting it into the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If constructing a string is your issue, yes, it is possible and can be done with a loop.

```
st = "This products are already in the list:"
for i in products:
    st += "\n-" + i
```

The variable `st` will then have the output you need to put in a `MessageBox`.
("\n" is a newline character, we use string concatenation to form the correct output string)

Comment: Yea I was just woundering if there was a method for doing this directly in the "command" field of the messagebox.